# How to perform a Non-Polymorphic JPQL query with JPA 1.0?

Tags: jakarta-ee, orm, jpa, jpql, openjpa

imagine i have 3 Entities, `Basic` <- `Sub` <- `SubSub`. I want to select `Basic` and `Sub` but not `SubSub`

I have already discovered that in JPA 2.0 I can have this query 
`SELECT b FROM Basic b WHERE TYPE(b) IN (Basic,Sub)`
But the implementation I have to work with is *apache-openjpa-1.2.3-SNAPSHOT*.

How can I accomplish the task with JPA 1.0? I'm open for anything. Can I query for the Discriminator Column (plain SQL or JPQL)? Is there some kind of queryHint? Can it be solved by not using Inheritance but some sort of Composition?

I'd appreciate your help. thx

Comment: JPA1.2 doesn't exist. Perhaps you mean JPA1.0

Comment: 8[ you'Re right. me is *embarrased*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test, but I think that you need something similar to this:

```
SELECT b FROM Basic b WHERE b NOT IN (FROM SubSub)
```

Comment: This is a very goog idea :)

Though I guess it would be like this.
`SELECT b FROM Basic b WHERE b NOT IN (SELECT s FROM SubSub s)`
wrong? 

Still seems like a workaround, but a nice one :)

Comment: Yes, but I think that in JPA the "SELECT" part is optional in this case. Anyway, your query should work also. However, i don't see this as a workaround, i see this as the proper way to do it. In fact I like it more than the JPA 2.0. alternative that you pasted... (because you really want the Basics that are not SubSubs, the query is logic.). If it works, please don't hesitate to mark the answer as accepted :)

Comment: I won't hesitate, thank you very much :)

I just called it workaround because I guess you couldn't select `Basic`s and `SubSub`s leaving the middle ones out?!? But, who cares. thats not what I need anyway... .  Since I'm using `SingeTableInheritance` would `SELECT b FROM Basic b WHERE b.id NOT IN (SELECT s.id FROM SubSub s)` improve performance?

Anyway, thx again.

Comment: I think that there is not an improvement of performance in this case, because JPA is already using the ID to check equality... And I think you do it less clear, and less decoupled (for example, if you change the name of your identifier, or if you even make a composite identifier in the future, this query would start failing), so i think the first approach is better IMHO.

Comment: Did it work? please mark the answer as correct if so, i will erase it if not. Thanks!

Comment: Be patient please. I'm currently rewriting a whole lot of entities (introducing inheritance). I needed this info to decide if I can go this way. It may take a week or so until I can test it, though I'm pretty sure it is going to work.

Comment: I must have forgot about this and I don't even remember if it worked. Nonetheless I'll mark your answer as accepted. Sorry for the delay (1 year, 4 months, 14 days lol :)

Comment: Well, you told me to be patient and so i did! Lol!